# Can vCenter 4 authenticate and authorize against a virtual directory server?

Tags: active-directory, vmware-vcenter

I am looking into Identity managment in our environment. We currently use Active Directory and Sun's Enterprise Directory server (6.3). I was wondering if I used the Virtual Directory Server of the Enterprise Directory server, would we be able to point the vCenter clients to this Directory service for authentication and authorization rather than at the AD source. The reason for this is that we have more users we want to add to the management role of this server but not all are in AD, a fair number are in the Sun LDAP v3. directory.

Thanks in advance

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that the VC manager can be used to configure LDAP authentication against sun's LDAP provider, as opposed to using the underlying AD.

Comment: You can configure ESX hosts to use non-AD LDAP user authentication fairly simply but I'm not aware of any way to reconfigure vCenter to use anything but Windows Authentication - can you expand on this with some hints on _how_ to do it.